# Is Koopman operator just like curve fitting?

Tags: robotics, koopman-operator

I am a beginner in Koopman operators，and I want to apply it to the robotics. But I think the Koopman operator approximated by EDMD is more like a fitting tool. Because we always choose some dictionary functions $\Phi=\left \{ \phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),\dots,\phi_n(x)   \right \} $, and the approximation of koopman operator is $K$ that satisfy $\Phi_{k+1}=K\Phi_{k}$, taking $\phi_1$ as an example, we get $$\phi_1(x_{k+1})=K_{11}\phi_1(x_k)+K_{12}\phi_2(x_k)+\ldots+K_{1n}\phi_1(x_k).$$
Doesn't it seem like a curve fitting?

Taking a simple discrete nonlinear system as an example,
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k+1}
 \\x_{2,k+1}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2*x_{1,k}
 \\x_{2,k}-x^2_{1,k}
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

- consider the fitting method

we will choose the basis function(like dictionary functions)$\Phi=\left \{ x_{1,k},x_{2,k},x^2_{1,k}\right\} $, and we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k+1}
 \\x_{2,k+1}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a  &b  &c \\
d  &e  &f \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k}
 \\x_{2,k}
 \\x^2_{1,k}
\end{bmatrix} $$.
And we can solve the fitting problem and get $a=2,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=1,f=-1$.

- consider EDMD method
  $$\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k+1}
   \\x_{2,k+1}
   \\x^2_{1,k+1}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =\begin{bmatrix}
  a  &b  &c \\
  d  &e  &f \\
  g  &h  &i 
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,k}
   \\x_{2,k}
   \\x^2_{1,k}
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$.And we can use the EDMD method and get $a=2,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=1,f=-1,g=0,h=0,i=4$.

I am confused about the modeling effect of the EDMD method and the fitting method seem similar(may be not for controlling, but the effect also doesn't seem very good).

I don't think this will have a very good effect in application, if we can't find the "best" dictionary functions(for EDMD method) or the basis functions(for fitting method)，and this situation is very common in applications. I may have a misunderstanding about the application of the Koopman operator, and I hope you can help me.

Comment: The idea is to make the function system large enough. Note also that you approximate the full functions. That is, if the dynamic is given as $x_{k+1}=F(x_k)$, then $$\phi_1(F(x)) \approx K_{11}\phi_1(x)+K_{12}\phi_2(x)+...+K_{1n}\phi_n(x)$$ etc. should be close for all $x$ from a suitable domain.

Comment: I update the problem description, and I still doubt the effect of the Koopman operator approximation in application. For the effect of modeling, Koopman operator and fitting method seem similar. If we can't find the good dictionary functions, the effect of controlling will not be good. Koopman operator method needs 3 more parameters to optimize in the new problem description， this may be good for controlling, but I think the effect is similar to the fitting method.

Comment: Yes, it is a nice theory with scarce applications. There was some recent renewed interest from the direction of neural networks, setting these up to learn the functions $\phi_k$ and the $K$ matrix. I could imagine that some calculations were done using Fourier or wavelet bases, that is, not a specifically adapted function system but an universal one, perhaps favoring the function class of $F$.

Comment: Perhaps a more effective koopman operator approximation algorithm or an algorithm with guiding value for dictionary function selection is needed.  Neural network may be a nice choice, but I still want to find real-time and effective online modeling algorithms to control the robot. Anyway, thank you for your comment.